# What are some good signal and image processing blogs worth following?

Tags: image-processing

Are there some good sites or blogs where I can keep myself updated on the latest news and papers about image and signal processing research, or I should just check out "classical" providers like IEEE Transactions, Elsevier, etc?

Comment: **NOTE:** (to all users) - While such questions are generally considered subjective and not fit for the StackExchange network, there is some benefit to such questions especially in niche areas. Similar sites such as [math.se], [stats.se], [cstheory.se] have the occasional soft-questions and requests for resources (the key word being _occasional_). If such questions become all too common here, then we'll have to rethink our policy on this.

Comment: Although such questions don't fit here, it is highly useful to newcomers. So instead of having many similar questions, it would be great to have a single question and a summarized answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are many for different subjects -

1. Efg's algorithm collection : http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/ImageProcessing/index.html
2. DSP Forum : http://www.dsprelated.com/
3. Data compression - http://datacompression.info/
4. About rendering - http://www.realtimerendering.com/portal.html
5. For all research papers - http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/guesthome.jsp
6. Resources on Mp3 and Audio - http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/docs/index.php
7. Steve on Image Processing - http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/
8. Image Processing and Retrieval http://savvash.blogspot.com/
9. Accelerated Image Processing - http://visionexperts.blogspot.com/
10. The Digital Signal Processing Blog - http://centerk.net/dspblog/
11. Noise & Vibration Measurement Blog - http://blog.prosig.com/
12. Image Processing with Matlab, Open Blog - http://imageprocessingblog.com/

Comment: Good list, but I should point out that the 3rd link doesn't work!

Answer (score 11):

Igor over at [Nuit Blanche](http://nuit-blanche.blogspot.com/) does a good job keeping up with publications in the field of Compressive Sensing.

Comment: Please note the message under the question: `please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.`

Comment: I concur. Nuit Blanche is an excellent blog about one of the most powerful method in image&signal processing - compressive sensing. It keep abreast of all the new methods, has a lot of links, reviews and comparisons. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressive_sensing

Answer (score 5):

Check out the Image Processing blog by [Steve Eddins](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/) from The Mathworks.

Comment: Please note the message under the question: `please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.`

Answer (score 4):

Image Processing with Matlab, [Open Blog](http://imageprocessingblog.com/).
hands-on, with the Matlab code of the problem and with clear, easy to follow documentation.
Open for people to present their work in image processing with Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

- [Machine Vision 4 Users](http://machinevision4users.blogspot.nl/) is a very practical blog on machine vision. Regular posts on camera's, lenses, software, lighting and the wole package that is necessary when developing machine vision setups.
- [CVPapers](http://www.cvpapers.com/index.html) is a site with free downloadable papers about the latest computer vision conferences, which can be useful if you do not have access to very expensive paper databases.
- [Blog of Teledyne Dalsa](http://blog.teledynedalsa.com/) has very wide subjects, but sometimes has posts that are very detailed about image processing.

Answer (score 2):

The one that has just started and is good for not only signal processing but also other fields of electrical engineering is [**Minutify**](http://www.minutify.com).
The link to the website is: [**http:www.munitify.com**](http://www.minutify.com)
The sections on this website/blog are: **DSP**, **Communications**, **Analog**, **RF**, **ASIC** and looks like each article is written by an expert in his/her field.

Answer (score 1):

i dunno why the original DSP "blog" (it's actually more of a BBS) on USENET is not mentioned.  that is the newsgroup *comp.dsp* .  one can get it the traditional way (an NNTP server like [Eternal September](http://www.eternal-september.org/)) but you will need a mail client that knows how to do NNTP (the one i am using is Thunderbird) or with [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.dsp) which has gotten progressively suckier as time rolls on.  [DSP Related](http://www.dsprelated.com/) (mentioned above) also has a port to *comp.dsp*.  the newsgroup is unmoderated so sometimes we just shoot the shit and discuss life (sometimes through the engineering lens).

Answer (score 0):

To complete the list I'd like to add a couple of weblogs that I personally follow:

1.[Aishack](http://aishack.in)  (covers basic to advanced algorithms, intuitively and practically)

2.[Py Image Search](http://pyimagesearch.com) A blog, specialized on AI, image processing and computer vision with stress on python implementation.

3.[Shervin Emami's blog](http://www.shervinemami.info) I'm not sure if it is still being updated.

4.[Fun Vision](http://funvision.blogspot.com) is also a good place I assume.