# DSP related websites and blog posts

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, dsp-core

Do you guys know good DSP related websited and blog posts?
I know that for example there is this site called **[Minutify](http://www.minutify.com)**:
http://www.minutify.com
which is blog posts regarding all areas of electrical engineering including DSP.
Do you guys know of similar resources?

Comment: I've recently started publishing image processing related articles implemented in C#. Would it be considered in bad style if I post a link to my own website? -- Dewald

Comment: Feel free to post the link to your site as an answer to [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-are-some-good-signal-and-image-processing-blogs-worth-following). However, please make sure to include an overview about the focus of the site (as opposed to just the link).

Comment: We really only want to have [one post](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-are-some-good-signal-and-image-processing-blogs-worth-following) with a catalog of sites, so you're welcome to include Minutify as an answer there--just make sure to follow the guidelines in the post notice on providing detail and context.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I did not know this and really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to comp.dsp,there is ongoing work on assembling all the dsp related sites and blogs together. It is a comprehensive list of all the available resources on DSP. The link is http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/195.php.